# How can I fix nuxt js static site links leading to network error?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a very basic nuxt.js application using JSON in a local db.json file, for some reason the generated static site links leading to network error, but I can access them from the url or page refresh.

**nuxt config**

```
generate: {
    routes () {
      return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/projects')
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data.map((project) => {
            return '/project/' + project.id
          })
        })
    }
  },
```

**main root index page**

```
    data() {
 return {
  projects: []
 }
},

async asyncData({$axios}){

let projects = await $axios.$get('http://localhost:3000/projects')
return {projects}
}
```

**single project page**

```
data() {
      return {
        id: this.$route.params.id
      }
    },

    async asyncData({params, $axios}){

    let project = await $axios.$get(`http://localhost:3000/projects/${params.id}`)
    return {project}

    }
```

[image: nuxt.js]

P.S. I have edited the post with the code for the main and single project page

Comment: Do you use `asyncData`, `fetch` or `middleware` for dynamic routes displayed above?

Comment: @aBiscuit Yes, in main root index page as follows:
`async asyncData({$axios}){

      let projects = await $axios.$get('http://localhost:3000/projects')
      return {projects}

      }
`

In single project page as follows:
`
data() {
          return {
            id: this.$route.params.id
          }
        },

        async asyncData({params, $axios}){

        let project = await $axios.$get(`http://localhost:3000/projects/${params.id}`)
        return {project}

        }
`

Comment: It is hard to point to exact issue without seeing the full picture, but general idea is that `asyncData` hook does not work on client-side (e.g. navigating from another page via link), but works on server-size (e.g. direct URL request). Likely, issue is with axios configuration. You have to make sure everything is configured correctly by debugging the error you get from response. I would try to remove `localhost:3000` from request URL and keep absolute path only, since it is the same domain. Changing to `$axios.$get('/projects')`.

Comment: I'll try this now and update you, thanking you

Comment: @aBiscuit - I am getting ` Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/projects/1. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). ` in console.

I have also tried keeping the absolute path but still getting the same network error. I have also uploaded the project on github (if you have some spare time to look into it)
[link](https://github.com/saadkhaan/b.git)

Comment: Thank you for providing project details. How do you serve `db.json`? I can't see it being imported in current app, therefore running or building will not work.

Comment: I do with `json-server --watch db.json`

Comment: Try passing the option `--no-cors` to disable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

https://github.com/typicode/json-server#cli-usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues with server-side requests of your application are caused by conflicts of ports on which app and `json-server` are running.

By default, both `nuxt.js` and `json-server` run on `localhost:3000` and requests inside `asyncData` of the app sometimes do not reach correct endpoint to fetch `projects`.

Please, check [fixed branch](https://github.com/acidbiscuit/b/tree/bug/resolve-async-data-issue) of your project's fork.

To ensure issue is easily debuggable, it is important to separate ports of API mock server and app itself for `dev`, `generate` and `start` commands.

Note updated lines in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
const baseURL = process.env.API_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'

export default {
  server: {
    port: 3001,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  },
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/axios', {
      baseURL
    }]
  ],
  generate: {
    async routes () {
      return axios.get(`${baseURL}/projects`)
        .then((res) => {
          return res.data.map((project) => {
          return '/project/' + project.id
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

This ensures that API configuration is set from a single source and, ideally, comes from environmental variable `API_BASE_URL`.

Also, app's default port has been changed to `3001`, to avoid conflict with `json-server`.

`asyncData` hooks have been updated accordingly to pass only necessary `path` for a request. Also, `try..catch` blocks are pretty much required for `asyncData` and `fetch` hooks, to handle error correctly and access error specifics.

Comment: I tried the forked repo, seems I might be missing something as the network error is still appearing.
I have hosted the static files on netlify [link](https://saadkhan.netlify.com)

Comment: First, make sure that you are using specific branch of the fork. Second, deployed project with baseURL in browser as `localhost:3000` will only work if user is running `json-server` on your machine at the same time. Using `json-server` should only only be valid for development. For project deployment you need API to be hosted separately.